# При добавление сущности , не добавляются зависимости , hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Класс Order

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

@Entity
@Table(name = "order", schema = "ksis_onlinestore", catalog = "")
public class OrderEntity
{
@Id
@Column(name = "id_order", nullable = false)
private int idOrder;
@Column(name = "date", nullable = true)
private Date date;
@Column(name = "time", nullable = true)
private Time time;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_customer", referencedColumnName = "id_customer", nullable = false)
private CustomerEntity customer;


public int getIdOrder()
{
    return idOrder;
}




public void setIdOrder(int idOrder)
{
    this.idOrder = idOrder;
}

public Date getDate()
{
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date)
{
    this.date = date;
}

public Time getTime()
{
    return time;
}

public void setTime(Time time)
{
    this.time = time;
}

public CustomerEntity getCustomer()
{
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(CustomerEntity customer)
{
    this.customer = customer;
}
}
```

Класс Customer

```
package dao;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Collection;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "ksis_onlinestore", catalog = "")
public class CustomerEntity
{
@Id
@Column(name = "id_customer", nullable = false)
private int idCustomer;
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = true, length = 45)
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = true, length = 45)
private String lastName;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Collection<CreditCardEntity> creditCards;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
private Collection<OrderEntity> orders;


public int getIdCustomer()
{
    return idCustomer;
}

public void setIdCustomer(int idCustomer)
{
    this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
}

public String getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName)
{
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Collection<CreditCardEntity> getCreditCards()
{
    return creditCards;
}

public void setCreditCards(Collection<CreditCardEntity> creditCards)
{
    this.creditCards = creditCards;
}

public Collection<OrderEntity> getOrders()
{
    return orders;
}

public void setOrders(Collection<OrderEntity> orders)
{
    this.orders = orders;
}
}
```

Добавление в базу данных:

```
package main;

import dao.CustomerEntity;
import dao.OrderEntity;
import hibernateUtil.HibernateSessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class AppMain
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Session session =         HibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    CustomerEntity customerEntity = new CustomerEntity();
    OrderEntity orderEntity = new OrderEntity();

    customerEntity.setFirstName("newTest");
    customerEntity.setLastName("1");


    orderEntity.setDate(new Date(2012, 11, 11));
    orderEntity.setTime(new Time(12, 12, 12));
    orderEntity.setCustomer(customerEntity);
    HashSet<OrderEntity> orderEntities = new HashSet<OrderEntity>();
    orderEntities.add(orderEntity);
    customerEntity.setOrders(orderEntities);

    session.save(customerEntity);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    HibernateSessionFactory.shutdown();
}
}
```

Comment: В базе данных реально появляется только Customer, Order не добавляется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в аннотацию параметр, указывающий на необходимость [каскадных операций](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbqm/index.html) со связанными сущностями:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Collection<OrderEntity> orders;
```

Comment: Добавил, теперь кидает  Exception                                              Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`ksis_onlinestore`.`order`, CONSTRAINT `customerFK` FOREIGN KEY (`id_customer`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id_customer`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: В самой БД , у Order есть поле id_customer, которое является вторичным ключом , со свойствами  DELETE = CASCADE , UPDATE = CASCADE.